# Can kernel change its block size?

Tags: cuda

The title can't hold the whole question: I have a kernel doing a stream compaction, after which it continues using less number of threads.

I know one way to avoid execution of unused threads: returning and executing a second kernel with smaller block size.

What I'm asking is, provided unused threads diverge and end (return), and provided they align in complete warps, can I safely assume they won't waste execution?

Is there a common practice for this, other than splitting in two consecutive kernel execution?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit of *execution* scheduling and *resource* scheduling within the SM is the warp - groups of 32 threads.

It is perfectly legal to retire threads in any order using `return` within your kernel code.  However there are at least 2 considerations:

1. The usage of `__syncthreads()` in device code depends on having every thread in the block participating.  So if a thread hits a `return` statement, that thread could not possibly participate in a future `__syncthreads()` statement, and so usage of `__syncthreads()` after one or more threads have retired is illegal.
2. From an execution efficiency standpoint (and also from a resource scheduling standpoint, although this latter concept is not well documented and somewhat involved to prove), a warp will still consume execution (and other) resources, until all threads in the warp have retired.

If you can retire your threads in warp units, and don't require the usage of `__syncthreads()` you should be able to make fairly efficient usage of the GPU resources even in a threadblock that retires some warps.

For completeness, a threadblock's dimensions are defined at kernel launch time, and they cannot and do not change at any point thereafter.  All threadblocks have threads that eventually retire.  The concept of retiring threads does not change a threadblock's dimensions, in my usage here (and consistent with usage of `__syncthreads()`).

Although probably not related to your question directly, [CUDA Dynamic Parallelism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism) could be another methodology to allow a threadblock to "manage" dynamically varying execution resources.  However for a given threadblock itself, all of the above comments apply in the CDP case as well.

Comment: Excellent answer Robert, and very useful.  I'm on a Jetson with compute capability 3.2, doesn't support CUDA Dynamic Parallelism.  I do need __syncthreads(), so I decided to compact all thread with actual job, and leave the rest with many __syncthreads() prior to return. The alternative is compacting and relaunching smaller kernel, but I'm worry about the launching time overhead.